# Performing functions with valueForKey

Tags: swift, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to get my app to perform functions. I have two attributes per item (quantity and price) that I want to multiply together and then total for all the didSelectRow items on the list. There is two sections on my tableView. Section 0 is regular and moved to section 1 with didSelectRow. (I only explain this because it comes into play further down)

My code so far is...

```
`func cartTotalFunc() {

    itemFetchRequest().returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try moc.executeFetchRequest(itemFetchRequest())
        print("===\(results)")

        // Calculate the grand total.
        var grandTotal = 0
        for order in results {


            let SLP = order.valueForKey("slprice") as! Int
            let SLQ = order.valueForKey("slqty") as! Int
            grandTotal += SLP * SLQ
        }
        print("\(grandTotal)")
        cartTotal.text = "$\(grandTotal)" as String

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

`

slprice and slqty are strings in Core Data. I am trying to cast them as Int so they will do the arithmetic. I had this working but it totaled every item instead of only the crossed off ones (section 1). I gave it a rest for a while and now when I come back to try to work on it again Xcode is giving me an error of, "can not Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x104592ae8) to 'NSNumber' (0x1051642a0)."

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: It looks like you're getting the value back as a string.  Try doing `let SLP = Int(valueForKey("slprice") as! String)`.

Comment: Thank you. That got that back working. Any suggestions are why it is totaling all items instead of only the didSelectRow? I call the function when the item is selected and moved to section 1 (selected) and it works like it is supposed to, only it includes all the items in section 0 as well. (sorry if that's not as clear as it needs to be, it sounds confusing to me)